# what is 'variable.whatever' in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have this line of code:

```
<cfset variable.currentCategory = 0>
```

I want to know what the `variable. part is. Does this have something to do with session variables? I have seen 'session.' before in CF, but not this. I am working with a huge amount of code and CF is not my wheelhouse. I can't tell if this is something with ColdFusion, or something defined elsewhere in the code that I just haven't found yet. Due to the nature of the question, it has made it very hard to look for an answer on google (try googling coldfusion variable lol). Thanks.

**Edit**
This line is specifically 'variable' and not the 'variables' scope. I think it has something to do with scopes, but I don't know what.

Comment: FYI: Rolled back to previous version because the crux of the question is the missing "s".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the variables scope or the session scope. It is a variable names "variable" that contains a struct. It is possibly a typo, or possibly a very poorly named variable.

Comment: +1. I have seen `variable` (without the "s") used in a very old app. In that case it was a mistaken attempt to use the proper `variables` scope.

Comment: Can you additionally tell me if there is any benefit to having this custom struct 'variable' as opposed to referencing the default variables.currentCategory?

Comment: Probably not. There are certainly good reasons to use structs is the variables scope, but to actually name one of them "variable" would just be silly.

Answer (score 2):

There are several scopes available in ColdFusion, variables and session being just two of them.  Every variable you create in CF exists in a scope. The variables scope is the default scope used.  So if you do `<cfset foo = "bar" />` this is the same as `<cfset variables.foo = "bar" />`.

You can find more about ColdFusion scopes in the ColdFusion Documentation: [ColdFusion 9](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff1.html), [ColdFusion 10](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff1.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought this was it too at first, but the syntax is 'variable' and not 'variables'. So, I'm still confused :/

Comment: this answer is incorrect because the code says `variable.` not `variables.`

Comment: Make sure that you mark Sean's answer as the correct one so he gets credit.

Comment: Jason is right, I read the question too quickly and did not see the "variable." vs "variables.".  My guess would be it was a typo, but yes, it is creating a structure called "variable" with a single key called "currentCategory".

Answer (score 1):

You can define values in the `session` scope like you said. You can also define them in the `variables` scope, which is probably what they were intending to do here. What they've really done is create a new structure called variable. So if below that line you do `<cfdump var="#variable#">` it will dump out that entire structure. My guess is they messed up and meant to type `variables`.

Comment: To add to this, if you write `<cfset variable.currentCategory = 0>`, it's the same as saying `<cfset variables.variable.currentCategory = 0>`. It's important to have the `s` at the end of the scope if you want to define the `variables` scope explicitly!

Comment: FYI, I modified the wording above and changed "scope" to "structure" to avoid confusion.